# Printing Prime Numbers to N value

Tags: java, methods, primes

This program is supposed to print all the prime numbers up to an int that you enter, for example:

```
 Enter a Number: 
 20
 2
 3
 5
 7
 11
 13
 17
 19
```

I just cannot get my program to work, I really don't know what to do, so if someone could review it and try to fix it, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class PrimeGenerator {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    int number = k.nextInt();
    PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator();
    System.out.println(matt.nextPrime(number));
}

private int number;

public PrimeGenerator(int n) {
 number = n;
}

public int nextPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime){
            return i;
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; what precisely doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear what is not working. Error? Exception? Wrong output?

Comment: please remove the JavaScript tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already there actually. You've just got a mistake in the program-flow.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            prime = false;
        }
    }
    if (prime){
        return i; //<-- this return will terminate nextPrim
    }
}
```

Things to fix/improve:

- `nextPrim` would need to return a value within every possible program-branch. This means: consider the case where `nextPrim` doesn't find any number in the given range and steps out of the loop. Now the program would be stuck without any return-value.
- Instead of returning the first prim-number found, you could print that found prim-number and keep the generator running. Nice, easy and solves the hassle with returning anything, since you now can simply declare `nextPrim` as `void`. I'd recommend renaming it to `printPrims` or something like that to make this change clear.
- Passing `number`: You can save a bit of effort by only passing `number` once to the prim-generator. The simplest solution would be to pass it to `nextPrim`/`printPrims`. Now you can remove the instance-variable `number` and the constructor, which solves the issue with th e signature of the constructor.
- 1 is not a prim-number to be pedantic. So let's be pedantic and start the outer loop in `printPrims` with 2, so that 2 will be the first number that is checked for being a prim.

So let's put this into code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int number = k.nextInt();
        PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator();
        matt.printPrims(number);
    }

    public void printPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            boolean prime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                 if (i % j == 0) {
                     prime = false;
            }
        }
        if (prime){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

A few general hints:

- Work through compiler errors. They tell you precisely where and what errors occur within your code.
- Think about the flow of your program before even implementing it.
- Break the task down into smaller tasks and implement these one after another. As an example: for this problem first print out all numbers in the range `2, number`. Afterwards go a step further and add functionality to filter out prim-numbers. Now you've got two components that you can easily test independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there but your `nextPrimes` function was terminating prematurely when you returned `i`, try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
    int number = k.nextInt();
    printPrimesUptoN(number);
  }

  public static void printPrimesUptoN(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
      boolean isPrime = true;
      for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
        if(i % j == 0){
          isPrime = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(isPrime)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Evns/0)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your code, maybe we can fix it together. First things first, you're missing a `return` statement in `nextPrime` and there's no empty default constructor `PrimeGenerator()` because you created a single-arg constructor. Try this:

```
public class PrimeGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int number = k.nextInt();
        // you probably want to pass your maximum value to the constructor
        PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator(number);
        // without a loop of some sort this will only print a single prime number, e.g.
        // Enter a Number:
        // 20
        // 2
        System.out.println(matt.nextPrime(number));
    }

    private int number;

    public PrimeGenerator(int n) {
        this.number = n;
    }

    // you're using the argument as upper boundary for your prime detection while not increasing your lower boundary
    // also you're checking if i is a prime here which you always start at 1. this should always return the same value because once you find a prime number you return
    // you should consider using an algorithm like Sieve of Eratosthenes (or advanced verions thereof) to determine if a given number is prime
    public int nextPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            boolean prime = true;

            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                }
            }

            if (prime){
                return i;
            }
        }

        // you need to return something at the end of this method or throw an exception
        throw new IllegalStateException("no more prime numbers available!");
    }
}
```

This is not a solution which will yield the results you're expecting but it will compile at least. From that point you can move forward and fix the algorithmic issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your original error was in.

```
PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator();
```

Error:

```
PrimeGenerator.java:7: error: constructor PrimeGenerator in class PrimeGenerator cannot be applied to given types;
    PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator();
                          ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Notice that you had a method with the same name as you class, but I don't think you were using it as a constructor and if you were it took an int which you didn't give it. Your method on line 13 was:

```
public PrimeGenerator(int n) {
 number = n;
}
```

Try doing

```
new PrimeGenerator().nextPrime(number);
```

Instead

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeGenerator {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                int number = k.nextInt();
                new PrimeGenerator().nextPrime(number);
        }   

        public void nextPrime(int number) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                        boolean prime = true;
                        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                                if (i % j == 0) {
                                        prime = false;
                                }   
                        }   
                        if (prime){
                                System.out.println(i);
                        }   
                }   
        }   
}
```

Optionally, to use your original constructor, you could separate this out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeGenerator {

        private int number; 

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                int number = k.nextInt();
                // Initialize with a number.
                PrimeGenerator pg = new PrimeGenerator(number);
                pg.printPrimes();
        }   

        // This is the constructer you were misusing.
        public PrimeGenerator(int n) {
                number = n;
        }   

        public void printPrimes() {
                // Actually use your private number variable.
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                        boolean prime = true;
                        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                                if (i % j == 0) {
                                        prime = false;
                                }   
                        }   
                        if (prime){
                                System.out.println(i);
                        }   
                }   
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. Are you using an IDE? If so, which is it, else Why not?. If you consider yourself a beginner, be advised to used one, like Eclipse IDE or NetBeans IDE.
2. Regarding to your algorithm, at first glance, there is a compilation and a logic problems.
3. Compilation problem is when the execution of your class not work. In this case the method `nextPrime(int number)` MUST return an `int`. Although you put return clause, the method is not returning any value when prime is `false`. You could easily spot this problem with an IDE.
4. Another compilation problem, the sentinel or variable `i` is INSIDE the for loop, and you are printing it's value OUTSIDE of it. Once again, the IDE would help you with this problem.
5. Logic problem is, you are returning a value if and only if the flag `prime` is true, so, when calling the method (supposing is working) you only obtain ONE value when you call `System.out.println(matt.nextPrime(number));`

The correct implementation would have these considerations:

1. The method doesn't return, i.e `public void nextPrime(number) { ...`, which means you don't need print in the main method, just call it.
2. The method actually prints the numbers.
3. In this way, you can check if `i % j` is different of zero, then you don't need to process more dividers, breaking the `for` loop.
4. Print it.
5. That's it.

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args) {
       .
       .
       .
       PrimeGenerator matt = new PrimeGenerator();
       matt.nextPrime(number);
   }

   public void printPrime(int number) {
       boolean prime = true;
       for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
           prime = true;
           for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j != 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
               }
           }
           if (prime) {
               System.out.println(i);
           }
       }
   }
   ```